# I want to show a list but page is empty

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin and after trying for 2 hours I'm not being able to make my page work...

The idea, is to get a list of names into SessionsList.cs, that will update automatically if the ObservableCollection changes, I'm not getting any errors but the page that should show the list is empty

**App.xaml.cs**

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace BetterApp
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public static bool IsUserLoggedIn { get; set; }
        public App()
        {    
            if (!IsUserLoggedIn)
            {
                MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
            }
            else
            {
                MainPage = new NavigationPage(new SessionsList());
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace BetterApp
{
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var lblUser = new Label
            {
                Text = "Username:"
            };
            var txtUser = new Entry
            {
                Placeholder = "Enter username"
            };
            var lblPass = new Label
            {
                Text = "Password:"
            };
            var txtPass = new Entry
            {
                Placeholder = "Enter password",
                IsPassword = true
            };
            var btnLogin = new Button
            {
                Text = "LOGIN"
            };            
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Padding = 30,
                Spacing = 10,
                Children = { lblUser, txtUser, lblPass, txtPass, btnLogin }
            };

            btnLogin.Clicked += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (Login.login(txtUser.Text, txtPass.Text))
                {
                    App.IsUserLoggedIn = true;
                    Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new SessionsList(), this);
                    await Navigation.PopAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Error", "Bad login details", "OK");
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**SessionsList.cs**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace BetterApp
{
    class SessionsList : ContentPage
    {
        ObservableCollection<Sessions> session = new ObservableCollection<Sessions>();
        public SessionsList()
        {
            App.IsUserLoggedIn = false;

            var list = new ListView();            
            list.ItemsSource = session;
            var btnRefresh = new Button
            {
                Text = "REFRESH"
            };
            btnRefresh.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
            {
                UpdateSessions();
            };
        }

        public void UpdateSessions()
        {
            session.Add(new Sessions { name = "Rob Finnerty" });
        }
    }
}
```

**Sessions.cs**

```
namespace BetterApp
{
    class Sessions
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm missing any detail, please let me know to improve my question :)

Comment: "not being able to make my page work" - what does this mean?  Define "not work".  Does it throw an error or crash or give a compiler error?  What specifically is it doing (or not doing) that you need help with?  You posted the code for two pages - which page is the problem?  And where is the XAML for the page?

Comment: hello @Jason, as mentioned in the question title "page is empty" and in my explanation "The idea, is to get a list of names into SessionsList.cs", I edited the question to make it more obvious. There is no XAML, the page is only SessionsList.cs.. sorry if I'm not giving all details I'm very new into Xamarin. Thank you for help

Answer (score 3):

you are creating UI elements but not doing anything with them

```
var list = new ListView();            
list.ItemsSource = session;
var btnRefresh = new Button
```

you need to add them to the page so that they are visible.  Because you have more than one element you need to use a `Layout` of some type

```
var layout = new StackLayout();
layout.Children.Add(list);
layout.Children.Add(btnRefresh);

// add to the page's Content
this.Content = layout;
```